# Three.JS: Spherical wireframe material /EdgesHelper control

Tags: javascript, three.js, drawing

New to Three.JS. Mostly I'm wondering about this being the right approach for what I want to do.

I'm trying render a certain type of wireframe material on a simple spherical geometry. I'm after this particular look:

[image]

My current efforts:

```
Note: Moved to Plunker below
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FrCUIwxH1IL3wFKwHSRJ?p=preview

Currently I'm using EdgesHelper to get a neat grid, I'm not sure on how to remove the vertical lines.

Ideally I need to control the distance between the horizontal lines and their opacity as well, but have been unable to do this with the helper. My other idea is to draw separate line geometries for each "line", but I think this is a bit of overkill. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Your "other" idea is best. But use `THREE.LineSegments` so you can render all the rings in a single line. Also use `BufferGeometry`. The geometry will be an array of _pairs_ of points. See http://jsfiddle.net/w67tzfhx/ to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a simple shader [like this](https://2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/simple_lines.html) be good enough for what you need?

vertex:

```
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

fragment:

```
uniform vec3 color1;
uniform float alpha1;
uniform vec3 color2;
uniform float alpha2;
uniform float lines;
uniform float linewidth;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
  float p = abs(fract(lines*vUv.y)*2.0-1.0);
  if(p < linewidth / 100.0){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color1, alpha1);
  }else{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color2, alpha2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi 2pha, thank you very much for your contribution. I'm not completely familiar with shaders despite reading some of the material on the Three.JS website about them. Would you mind explaining to me how this one works?

Comment: just view the source of the page. It is using [ShaderMaterial class](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial). View more of my [shadermaterial experiments here](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial). There are plenty of GLSL shader tutorials online.

Comment: Thanks 2pha. I have a night of studying your examples ahead of me. Next is to make the lines glow. Also many thanks for your extremely complete example - the controls helped me get a grasp on it.